# Upgraded to a larger SSD using a cloned copy of existing. Possible to extend the existing partition?

Tags: partitioning, ssd

I was using a 320GB magnetic drive and recently upgraded to a 500GB SSD.  The clone process worked but left me with an extra partition of 178GB unallocated space.

[image]

When I click on Move/Resize under /dev/sda6 this appears, showing no available space:

[image]

Is there a safe way to merge this available space into the existing partition `/dev/sda2`?

Comment: Just boot a live session, open GParted, resize the extended partition `sda2` and then you can resize `sda6` to use the remaining space.

Comment: The issue is that I am unable to resize the partition per other posts on AU.   I saw and read the thread linked above and while interesting, it did not solve the problem I am having.

Comment: Can't grab a screenshot of the sda2 context menu showing the grayed out move/resize option.  This appears whether using gparted as root on the same system, or booting from a Live CD and running gparted as root there.   Both places will not allow me to select move/resize for /dev/sda2 - the option is grayed out.

Comment: Note the key icons in your screen shot. They indicate the partition is in use. IIRC, to resize an extended partition, *all* the partitions it contains must be unmounted. This includes swap (which isn't really mounted, but can be in use). Boot from a live CD and check to be sure all the partitions on the disk are unused. You should then be able to resize the partitions.

Comment: I did use a Live CD, just didn't take screenshots.   It would not allow me to increase the sda2 partition beyond what it's current max value is.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to be booting from a live DVD or USB so that nothing is mounted.

Open Gparted from the Live media, and right click `sda2` to extend it and take all the remaining free space. This is your container for `sda6`.

After that, you can extend `sda6` to take up the new free space within the extended partition.

Comment: Growing a partition at its end is possible with gparted while the partition is mounted.

Comment: I tried both ways.  The maximum available space is shown in the second image above.

Comment: You need to extend sda2 first. @acoder

Comment: @Doarian, I've tried using gparted with the actual system and with a Live CD.   Both yield the same result, which is I am not allowed to extend sda2 beyond its current limit.    See second screenshot.    I tried swapoff and removed the swap, no effect.

Comment: Can't grab a screenshot of the sda2 context menu showing the grayed out move/resize option.  This appears whether using gparted as root on the same system, or booting from a Live CD and running gparted as root there.   Both places will not allow me to select move/resize for /dev/sda2 - the option is grayed out.